# Changed access permission & ownership but still cant access files & folders

Tags: windows-7, windows-xp, external-hard-drive, file-permissions

HDD from an old Win XP laptop is usb-connected to a Win7 laptop. I have changed the permission as well as the ownership of the drive and its sub folders, YET I can't access the content of the files and I get the same msg "can't open this photo because you do not have permission to access the file location"!

I have 150GB data on it which I need to access.  How do I access the data?

Comment: How did you take ownership of the folder exactly?  Can you post a screenshot of the ownership of the folder?

Comment: I am not sure how to get a screeshot but this is the procedure:

Comment: right click the drive-->properties--> security-->advanced-->owner-->edit

Comment: Ctrl + Print Screen will take a picture of the active window.  You can figure out the rest.

Comment: Thank you Ramhound for trying to help. I got the screenshot but I am apparently not allowed to post an img here as I have not enough reputation!!!